# How to invoke methods from .Net Dll using java

Tags: java

.Net dll contains two methods.ie GetStatus(),GetSum() .How Can i use two methods in java.

```
     INetServer iNetServer =
        (INetServer)Native.loadLibrary("C://Program Files (x86)//Java//jre1.8.0_121//bin//NetServer.dll", INetServer.class);
String strDateTime =new String();
int intNoOfUsers=0;
int intNoOfTrans = 0;
iNetServer.GetStatus("xx", "yyyzzz", strDateTime, intNoOfUsers, intNoOfTrans);
```

Iam getting Exception below:
          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetStatus': The specified procedure could not be found.

```
at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:245)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:566)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:542)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:528)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:228)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.GetStatus(Unknown Source)
at com.nipun.it.Dll.utils.AttendanceDll.main(AttendanceDll.java:30)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its "\\" vs "/" - "//" makes no sense.

Comment: I changes but its coming same exception.

Comment: So then you should also edit your question to reflect the changes